# Apex SendMail() method emails received when executed as anonymous but not from code

Tags: apex, email

We have been struggling with this for a day now and the answers on the web have not been helpful, so I'll be explicit in describing our issue.

We have implemented a wrapper method for `SendMail()` as follows:

```
@future
public static void sendEmail(List<String> receiver, String message) {
  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage messageOne = new 
  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
  messageOne.toAddresses = receivier;
  messageOne.optOutPolicy = 'FILTER';
  messageOne.subject = 'Flagged Client';
  messageOne.setSaveAsActivity(false);

  messageOne.plainTextBody = message;  
  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messageSent = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {messageOne};
  Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messageSent);
}
```

Our Deliverability configuration is as follows:

- Access Level: All mail
- Activate Bounce Management: True
- Enable compliance with standard email security mechanisms: True
- Enable Sender ID compliance: True
- Log activities for email recipients: True
- TLS: Preferred

Our testing results so far:

- When we send via *Test Deliverability*, messages are delivered and
  visible on the recipient email system (Gmail, not in SPAM folder).
- When we call this method from *Execute Anonymous*, messages are
  delivered and visible on the recipient email system (Gmail, not in
  SPAM folder).
- When we call from the app, however, messages are NOT
  delivered on the recipient email system (Gmail, and are not in SPAM
  folder).

Our Email Log Exports show these results (small sample):

```
"08/07/2018 20:16:01","97/81-01910-10EF96B5",R,"kevin.hiemenz@redargyle.com","salesforce+googleprod=redargyle.com__0-76917vvbf0hyr2@gkf9p2u9ufm8ue.29-9az0eam.cs19.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com","10.220.84.155",1762,0051N000004lu7D,"<-9wc4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000PD3XMP00Q1VfJU87TpiB3fTgZeZMag@sfdc.net>",,,,,,,"TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",yes
"08/07/2018 20:16:02","97/81-01910-10EF96B5",D,"kevin.hiemenz@redargyle.com","salesforce+googleprod=redargyle.com__0-76917vvbf0hyr2@gkf9p2u9ufm8ue.29-9az0eam.cs19.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com","74.125.197.27",1762,0051N000004lu7D,"<-9wc4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000PD3XMP00Q1VfJU87TpiB3fTgZeZMag@sfdc.net>",0,"1.051774",,,,,"TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",unverified
```

According to the Salesforce docs, the statuses `R` & `D` indicate success.[1](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_logs_format.htm&type=5)

In fact, the log entries look the same, with the same statuses, for the emails we sent via *Test Deliverability*.

Comment: And you see the future method in the Apex Jobs with status as "Completed"? As a test, I used your code in the post from a trigger on Account and it sent the email successfully.

Comment: Having the exact same issue at the moment.